# Error creating a color_attribute slot and bakes the AO onto this slot for multiple Objects

Tags: python, vertex-colors

I need a script, that batch processes the selected objects, creates a  color_attribute slot and bakes the AO onto this slot. This works fine with individual objects. However when I try to boundle it into a batch process, the script returns an error.

```
import bpy
                
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.data.color_attributes.new('AO', 'BYTE_COLOR', 'CORNER')
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='AO', target='VERTEX_COLORS')
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Mesh does not have an active color attribute "Object name"
```

Has someone an idea, how to solve this?
I'm at Blender Version 4.0.1

Comment: [link](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/105020)
[link](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/105152)
[link](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/103761)

I see that there was once a lot of discussion regarding this topic. However according to those links it should habe been solved which surprises me.

Comment: The workaround that fixed it for me, was to split it up into two segments so I'm first creating the color_attributes for every objekt and the baking starts once every object has its color attribute.